# How extract some part of a javascript from a webpage using jsoup?

Tags: javascript, android, jsoup

i want to extract some data from blow script

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#areaName").val(1);$("#state").val(29);$("#city").val(1);
  $("#subareaName").val(1);$("#lane").val(1);
}
```

like areaName value = 1, state value = 29, city value = 1, subareaName value = 1, lane value = 1

How can i achieve this using jsoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsoup is html (xml) parser. You can use it to extract javascript from page source for example like this: `Elements scripts = document.select("script");`

Then you will have to parse the script by yourself. You can use regex to do so.
Here is an example.

```
    final String propertyName = "areaName";
    final String regex = "#" + propertyName + ".*?val\\((.*?)\\)";
    final String script = "$(document).ready(function(){ \n"
            + "  $(\"#areaName\").val(1);$(\"#state\").val(29);$(\"#city\").val(1);\n"
            + "  $(\"#subareaName\").val(1);$(\"#lane\").val(1);\n"
            + "}";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(script);

    if (matcher.find() && matcher.groupCount() > 0) {
        String areaName = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.println(propertyName + ": " + areaName);
    }
```